# Bytes in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, byte

I have the following struct that stores every byte of the added element in subsequent positions of the vector :

```
struct StashVector {
    int size; // Size of each space
    int next; // Next empty space
              // Dynamically allocated array of bytes:
    std :: vector<char> storage;
    // Functions!
    void initialize(int sz);
    //void cleanup();
    int add(const void* element);
    void* fetch(int index);
    int count();
//  void inflate(int increase);
};
```

and its implementation :

```
void StashVector::initialize(int sz) {
    size = sz;      
    next = 0;
}

int StashVector::add(const void* element) {
    unsigned char* e = (unsigned char*)element;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        storage.push_back(e[i]);
    next++;
    return(next-1); // Index number
}

void* StashVector::fetch(int index) {
    assert(0 <= index);

    if (index >= next)
        return 0; // To indicate the end
                  // Produce pointer to desired element:
    return &(storage.at(index*size));
}

int StashVector::count() {
    return storage.size()/size; 
}
```

I want to use it for storing integers in it like so:

```
int main() {
    StashVector sv;
    sv.initialize(sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sv.add(&i);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j<sv.count(); j++) {
        cout << *(int*)sv.fetch(j) << endl;
    }
}
```

Here comes something that i dont understand. Because it stores the bytes of the element on different positions in the `vector`, the first four position in the `vector` (`sv.fetch(0)` , `sv.fetch(1)`,`sv.fetch(2)`,`sv.fetch(3)`) should be `00000000` `00000000` `00000000` `00000000` , which is equivalent to the binary representation of `int` as `0`, but when I try to print the elements of the vector in the `for`-loop, it displays the numbers directly. Is it because I initialized it with the `sizeof(int)`, it prints 4 bytes at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it prints four bytes at a time, since you ask it to print ints. If you want to see each byte individually, you could loop through the entire vector and print each element individually. It would then be a good idea to cast the char to an int before printing, so that you get the number and not some control character.

```
for (int n : sv.storage) 
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/WRQtaa)